# Is it possible to create Document library on subsite automatically when someone adding new item to list on main site by using SharePoint Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I`m trying to make SharePoint Workflow which will automatically create Document Library on Subsite with name "Library for [item name]", where item name is title of just created item. Is it possible via SharePoint Workflow or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible via workflow, but there's an easiest way. You could simply implement an item event receiver which detects when an item is added and creates a document library.

You can refer to this link ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx) to better understand how to implement the item event receiver.